# Find an effective upper bound for this product

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Let $f$ be a primitive form of an even weight $k\geq 2$  for the full modular group $SL_2(Z)$ and $\lambda_f(n)$ be the $n$-th normalized Fourier coefficient. Define a multiplicative function $g$ by $g(p)=2$ if $\lambda_f(p)\neq 0$ and $g(p^\nu)=0$ whenever $\nu \geq 2$ or $\lambda_f(p)=0.$ Can someone give me an upper bound in terms of $\log{x}$ for the following product:
$$\prod_{p\leq x} \left(1+\frac{g(p)}{p}+\frac{g(p^2)}{p^2}+...+\frac{g(p^\nu)}{p^{\nu}}\right)=\prod_{\substack{p\leq x\\ \lambda_f(p)\neq 0}} \left(1+\frac{2}{p}\right)?$$
Many thanks.

Comment: What kind of bound are you looking for? Certainly one can just bound the product above by $\prod_{p \leq x} (1 + 2/p)$. It seems that this is the best one can hope for in general; if $f$ does not have CM then the set of primes $p$ for which $\lambda_f(p) = 0$ has density $0$.

Comment: @Daniel Loughran By  bound I mean that this product is less than an expression of $\log{x}.$

Comment: An argument similar to the proof of Mertens' theorem should give you what you want

Comment: What Daniel Loughran and Stanley Yao Xiao are saying is the following. $\prod_{p\leq x}(1+2/p)$ is trivally an upper bound for your product, and it is asymptotically a constant times $(\log x)^2$ by standard estimates. Moreoever, this is the best one can hope in general, i.e. the condition $\lambda(p)\neq 0$ usually does not make the product much smaller.

Comment: @GHfromMO Thank you for your answe! It is very sufficient for me.

Comment: @GHfromMO Is it true that $$ \prod_{p\leq x} \left(1+\frac{a}{p}\right)\leq \left(\frac{\log{x}}{\log{2}}\right)^a$$ for all non-negative integer $a$?

Comment: @KhadijaMbarki: No, this fails already for $x=2$ and $a=1$ (left hand side is $3/2$, right hand side is $1$).